# Not sure why 'relation' => 'AND' is not working in this code?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm not sure why `'relation' => 'AND'` is not working in the code below. If I use 'OR', it applies the first condition only, but if it's 'AND' it returns no posts. Yet there are posts that meet both conditions.

I think it has to do with the syntax, as I removed all other conditions, but still it's not returning records:

```
$similar = az_get_option( 'similar' );
if( !empty( $similar ) ){
    $catsz = get_the_terms ( get_the_ID(), array ('adcategory', 'adlocation'));                 
    $catsz = az_taxonomy_hierarchy( $catsz );
   if( !empty( $catsz ) ){
        $catsz = az_taxonomy_id_hierarchy( $catsz );
        $cat = end( $catsz ); $attr = array();
        $ads = new Wp_Query(array(
            'posts_per_page' => $similar,
            'post_type' => 'ad',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array( 
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'adcategory',
                    'terms'   => array( $cat )
                ),
                array(      
                    'taxonomy' => 'adlocation',
                    'terms' => array( $cat )
                )
            ),
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() )
        ));
                
        if( $ads->have_posts() ){
```

Comment: Please make sure to include a language tag in the future so people can find it

Comment: Please provide the data that should be returned, and the actual value of `$cat`

Comment: Its custom type  location and category, and $cat returns post id number, is that the info neede @trincot

Comment: no problem @Machavity

Comment: I am actually asking for the *acual* data that you believe matches the conditions and should be in the output. And please give the *actual* (literal) value of `$cat`.

Comment: $catsz  prints   218, 212, 183   and $cat prints  183   @trincot

Comment: I think you taught me something about the logic behinde it @trincot thanks, but still cant fix it :)

Comment: I fixed it thank you for your time @trincot I'll share it here, it may look  messy but I got the idea, if needs improvements to look pro let me know please

Comment: $catszl = wp_get_post_terms ( get_the_ID(), 'advert-location');     
     $catszl = adifier_taxonomy_hierarchy( $catszl );

Comment: added the above spinet and it looks like that :